# How to assign frontend submitted forms automatically to backend users, if backend users are 3-4 or may increase

Tags: php

How can I assign frontend submitted form to the backend users? Backend users are 3-4 in count and may increase any time, we have a special table and CRUD functionality to create users.

I tried the following way, but it's not working.

I created a table named auto_assign and inserted the submitted form count for each form submitted in that table, after that I took count of the backend users, now I have a count of both:
1. the total form submitted today
2. total count of backend users.

now I wanted to assign the form in following way

if we suppose that we have 5 forms and 3 backend users
form 1 must be assigned to user 1, 
form 2 must be assigned to user 2, 
form 3 must be assigned to user 3, 
form 4 must be assigned to user 1, 
form 5 must be assigned to user 2

and the form 6 whenever is submitted must be assigned to user 3 again and the flow must go on,

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

When you inserting form data fetch users id and calculate to whom you should assign current form. you should also fetch latest assigned form.

Pseudo code:

```
$myNewForm = some data

$myLatestInsertedForm = [assigned_user_id: 7]

$myUsers = [1,2,3,6,7,8] : 6

new_form_id = insert into form ();

//calculating 

if (assigned_user_id < max($myUsers)) {

    user_id = next(assigned_user_id, $myUsers)
} else {
    user_id = min($myUsers)
}


assing (new_form_id, user_id)
```